# Story about magic: Man's parents killed by mages, later discovers he is magic himself

Tags: story-identification, magic

I read this book years ago as a child. I do not know the author or when it was published. I vaguely remember the cover having an image of a man in armor in a desert.

What the plot consisted of, was that the man was a soldier for a kingdom that didn't like mages. In fact, his parents had been killed by them when he was really young. His station is on this armored train that is going through the desert. Somehow, a female elf tells him that he has magic which causes him to begin to remember things of his parents and how they could make all kinds of plants grow or something.

I think the magic involved some kinds of circles or colors of magic, but I'm not sure. I'm certain this was not a Magic: the Gathering novel and not a part of the Circles of Magic series either.

As I said, I don't remember a lot of the book, but I tried to. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could this have been a novelization of a video game perhaps?  Like, if FFVIII was novelized for example.  It does sound like it was adapted from some kind of RPG.

Comment: I don't think so. As I said, this was from years ago, in the early to mid nineties when I first read it but that doesn't mean it was published at that time. It's possible, but I haven't heard of any game that stirred any memory of this book/series.

Comment: This sounds an awful lot like a story I once read from the Dark Sun D&D setting. The mages that could make plants grow, etc would have been called preservers. By any chance did the story you remember involve a bit of glass that was formed when someone cast a spell (lightning perhaps) that fused the sand at the point of impact? Was the train in your story a sort of wagon train, pulled by large insectoid creatures?

Comment: "I read this book years ago as a child."  It would help if you could edit in when you were a child.  2005?  1995?  1955?  A range is all right.  It would also help if you could better define what "child" means.  When you were in elementary school?  High school?  Were you reading at your age level?  Or ahead?  Perhaps read over the [story-identification FAQ](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/30870) to see if it jogs your memory of additional details.

Comment: Elementary school. This would be during the early to late-no ties. I was born in 1988. This was above my level at the time, being a full length fantasy novel.

Comment: As for the dark sun novels, I have looked at the covers but none of them jog any memories. What is the title of the specific book that has these scenes in it.

Comment: Perhaps Magician by Raymond E. Feist.